# Problems with [$resource:badcfg] in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-resource

A problem happens when the active button to register.

Error: [$resource:badcfg]

CONTROLLER

```
>.controller("UserCreationController", function($scope, Users) {
>>$scope.usercreation = { 
>>        name: 'teste',
>>        email: 'teste',
>>        birthday: '12/4/1980'
};

>>$scope.cadastro = function () {
>>>Users.create($scope.usercreation); 
>>>}
>>>})
```

MODULE FACTORY

```
>.factory("Users", function($resource) {
>>        return  $resource(http://localsite.com.br/user/perfil",{},{
>>        create: {method: 'POST'}
});
})
```

Has anyone experienced this problem. 
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$scope.cadastro = function () {

Users.create($scope.usercreation); 

}
})
```

and

```
.factory("Users", function($resource) {

    return  $resource(http://localsite.com.br/user/perfil",null,{

    'create': {method: 'POST'}

});
})
```

Comment: Hello. Error still continues. :(

Comment: The problem was the service API. 

Very grateful for your attention and help.